# Drag & drop multiple items at once, as a stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a system that allows me to drag multiple selected items at once, but once dragging starts, they should collapse into a stack with an integer showing how much items are being dragged, not individual items that keep their relative position.

I've been looking at existing Drag & Drop implementations and got multi drag working but I can't seem to find a library that allows my to override the drag proxy with my own implementation.

Anyone has an idea how to accomplish this? Or should I look into writing my own Drag & Drop solution using HTML5 Drag & Drop API or another library?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `helper` to achieve this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#list-items [data-action="draggable"]').draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: function() {
      var selected = $('#list-items [data-action="draggable"].selected');
      if (selected.length === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        selected = $(this);
      }
      var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
      container.append('<div>' + selected.length + '</div>')
      container.append(selected.clone());
      return container;
    }
  });
  $('#list-items [data-action="draggable"]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected')
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: rgba(13, 173, 253, 0.37)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list-items'>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 1</li>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 2</li>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 3</li>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 4</li>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 5</li>
  <li data-action='draggable'>elem 6</li>
</ul>
```